# area of triangle in terms of squared edge lengths

Tags: geometry, triangles

It is well-known that the area of a triangle can be computed from the squared edge lengths $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$ as
$$
A 
= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2a^2b^2 + 2b^2c^2 + 2c^2a^2 - a^4 - b^4 - c^4}\\
= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 - 2 (a^4 + b^4 + c^4)}
$$
(See, e.g., [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html)).

When computing the above expression numerically, the expression under the root can sometimes become negative (in the order of machine precision). One can of course ignore that and set those values to zero, but nevertheless the my question:

Is there an alternative expression for $A$ in terms of $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$ that is numerically positive, e.g., the sum of squares?

Comment: "When computing the above expression numerically, the expression under the root can sometimes become negative (in the order of machine precision)." Request clarifying example.

Comment: Formula (18) of your linked "here" page gives the area in terms of squareroot of a sum of *squares* of three determinants, at definitely can cause no problems numerically, provided the numerical method doesn't produce a negative somehow from a squared real.

Comment: @coffeemath That's true, but I'm looking for something in terms of the squared edge lengths.

Comment: Nico--- So you mean maybe a sum of monomials in $a^2,b^2,c^2$ with perhaps some positive coefficients on the monomials? [I know of none such but that doesn't prove there isn't one.]

Comment: @coffeemath Indeed.

Comment: A polynomial in $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$ that yields $16A^2$ necessarily reduces to the formula shown under the root. (Holding any two values fixed leaves a quadratic in the third whose coefficients are uniquely determined.) Your goal seems to be *implementing* the formula with less (or *no*) sensitivity to machine-precision error. Something like [Horner form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) *might* help by reducing the number of operations used, but I don't know if the difference is appreciable w/mere quadratics. Computer scientists might be a better audience for this question.

Comment: A slightly more balanced way to write the expression in the square root is $a^2(b^2+c^2−a^2)+b^2(c^2+a^2−b^2)+c^2(a^2+b^2−c^2)$. I don't see any way to write it in a way that all intermediate results are positive, though it might be possible if you sort the edges $a\ge b\ge c$ and split it into various cases (i.e. the above for $a^2\le b^2+c^2$, and then one or more different expressions when $a^2>b^2+c^2$).

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the link you posted about Heron's formula, the expression that you have under the root comes from:
$(a+b+c)  (b+c-a)  (a+c-b)  (a+b-c)$

You can't have a triangle where one of the edges is bigger than the sum of the other two, so your expression is always positive if a, b and c are the edges of  a triangle.

You get negative values only when considering three segments that can't be put together to form  a triangle.

Comment: I'm looking for something in terms of the _squared_ edge lengths. I will try to make this even clearer in the post.

Comment: @Donald Oh thank you, I put the dollars. About Heron's formula, I didn't know this formula had a name, I just took it from the link he posted. Should I add a reference to it in the answer pretending that I know more than I do?

Comment: @Donald all right I named it in the answer